# How to pre-fill an Input type text with value in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I need to modify and update value in mongoDB.
I use a form to do it.
How to pre-fill an Input type text with value ?

Comment: [Input bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html)

Comment: My project is made with vue3.

Comment: I linked the Vue 3 docs, not that there's any difference in input bindings between Vue 2 and Vue 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your value from mongoDB to the v-model you are using for input in mounted hook:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getDataFromMongoDB(){
      // your existing code here...
      return 'Value from DB'
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.message = await this.getDataFromMongoDB()
  },
}
</script>

<template>
    <input v-model="message" />
</template>
```